# Is it unprofessional/rude to walk in for an interview without being invited?

Tags: interviewing, singapore

So I have been doing sales for quite awhile now, usually through door knocking and I'm getting used to all the rejections.

There's one company in Singapore that I really really wanted to join.

Is it okay to walk in without an appointment and ask their HR team if I can do a quick interview? Or will this come across as rude or unprofessional?

Comment: Well if it works it would show you're a skilled salesperson who knows how to close a deal.

Comment: I thought we already had a question on this but I can't find it. Regardless, [this external post](http://www.askamanager.org/2013/05/cold-calling-companies-and-showing-up-in-person-to-submit-a-resume.html) is pretty relevant.

Comment: In your **specific field**, it may be OK.  As you well know cold-calling is one of the world's great challenges, and rewards.  If you go for it, good luck!

Comment: Any chance you could informally meet someone at the company and then arrange an interview? Maybe they have a local hang-out or an up coming conference.

Comment: Please specify what field you work in, as answers will depend greatly on that.

Comment: I think this will blow up in your face like an ACME dynamite kit.

Comment: While it would show your sales skills, is it culturally appropriate? Gender appropriate for Singapore? Being a sales person is more than just "selling" it's also honoring the way your clients (employer) want to do business and how they are comfortable with the process. Please don't comment about me being sexist; I'm a female and a realist.

Answer (score 12):

Can't really speak for Singapore as there may well be significant differences in culture from where I am in the UK but here it would, more often then not be perceived negatively. I can imagine it *potentially* going over better in some very sales-lead environments where the majority of what they do is dealing with "cold" leads because they will view that sort of approach as being inline with their own model but otherwise it feels very intrusive.

Comment: It also depends on the field. In manual labor jobs, walking in is usually the **best** way to get a job. In office jobs, however, it is probably the opposite. OP doesn't state his field though.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen true - the field makes a big difference as to how this sort of thing would be responded too - the OP doesn't specify but does refer to sales in the question so I hadn't geared my answer to manual labor-type jobs.

Answer (score 4):

No, not HR. HR is the gatekeeper! HR has only the power to reject you, not hire you.

If you want to do this, you need to reach the decision-maker first and foremost and that will be the hiring manager. Just be careful how you do it, if you just show up, he'll tell you to apply online and/or to go through HR.

However, if you tell him, yes, I've already applied online this morning, but I also just wanted to drop off my paper resume so that you could put a face to the resume. This should take care of that objection. Just don't tell him that you've applied last week or last month (because he'll automatically assume that your resume got rejected already, and probably for a good reason). And don't lie either, if you say you applied in the morning, make sure that you did that.

Now, I could give you further tips, but I really need to know what type of company this is and what job you're applying for. Not every building will just allow you to walk in. Some will, but some won't. It really depends on the type of company.

How extensive is your LinkedIn network? How many degrees are you removed from someone working in that company? By the way, do you already live in Singapore? If you're just flying in for one day from very far away, it's amazing how accommodating people can be.

You say you're in sales, but sales rarely targets just one customer. For you to refine your technique, you'll need to try your approach on many different companies, before you try it on the one that you really care about. And even then, no approach is guaranteed to work, so you may get no offer from the company you want to work for, but you may instead get multiple offers from the companies that you do not care about (or simply zero offer from anyone). Is such a potential negative outcome ok with you?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not okay. That is a terrible idea and likely you will be ejected as soon as possible.
Interviewers need time to prepare as well as a time slot and room. They also need an opportunity to prescreen candidates to ensure they don't lose time on unsuitable applicants.
Sometimes it is okay to leave your resume in some specific circumstances, like for a job in local restaurant or small business, but it is unlikely that somebody will interview you without invitation.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's a terrible idea and doesn't work. It'd probably work for some manual labour job in a warehouse or something. For one thing, how are you going to find the HR? And supposing you do, that's a terrible way to meet someone to try and get a job.

Why would they even post a job if any random schmuck can "persuade" their way into a job? It makes you look desperate and stalkerish too.

And most HR probably don't take kindly to people trying to circumvent the process.

Comment: +1. My nephew got a job as a mechanic by having a 'walk in interview', but that's different to as described by the OP. The mechanic interview was talking to folks working outside, and showing off skills by talking shop and fixing some stuff.